# How to create a pie chart with equal wedges and labels

Tags: diagram, chart-design

How can I create a pie chart with 8 equal wedges which I can name tag outside the circle?

Charts will not let me make the design I want.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! You need to be far more specific. It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you have tried and where exactly you get stuck, and let us know what software you are using. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the benefit of a pie chart if all slices are the same?

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of tools that will make you do this. First that springs to mind is [**Google charts.**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

However, pretty much any graphic software will let you create this.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint is about the simplest pie chart generator

Answer (score 0):

Try LiveGap Charts ( http://charts.livegap.com ) . it's free online tool for generate charts.